# MySQL Join two tables on multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

**Table1:** 
*- id 

- name 

- table2_id1 

- table2_id2 

- table2_id3*

**Table2:** 
*- id 

- name*

Table1:

```
    id | name    | table2_id1 | table2_id2 | table2_id3
    1  | blabla  | 1          | 2          | 3 
    2  | blabla2 | 2          | 3          | 1
```

Table2:

```
    id | name
    1  | aaa 
    2  | bbb 
    3  | ccc
```

I would like to display a name from Table1 and many names from Table2 which are joined, example:

```
*blabla | aaa | bbb | ccc*
```

I hope you get what I mean.

EDIT:

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.name, Table2.name, Table2.name, Table2.name<BR>
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON<BR>
```

Comment: `SELECT t1.name, t2.name, t3.name, t4.name FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id=t1.table2_id1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t3 ON t3.id=t1.table2_id2 LEFT JOIN Table2 t4 ON t4.id=t1.table2_id3`. You have to join `Table2` for each column that you want joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use left join queries:

```
SELECT a.name as "name", b.name as "table2_id1_name", c.name as "table2_id2_name", d.name as "table2_id3_name" 
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON (a.table2_id1 = b.id)
LEFT JOIN Table2 C ON (a.table2_id2 = c.id)
LEFT JOIN Table2 d ON (a.table2_id3= d.id)
```

Hope it work as you expect. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name
FROM Table1 a, Table2 b, Table2 c, Table2 d
WHERE a.table2_id1 = b.id
AND a.table2_id2 = c.id
AND a.table2_id3= d.id
```

Comment: The last 2 should be `AND a.table2_id2 = c.id AND a.table2_id3= d.id`

Comment: What if lets say table2_id2 is NULL? Your query doesn't seem to work when there's a null.

Comment: answer depends on what you want ? what do you want if there's null? do you want to display null/blank?

Comment: Something like Shamsudheen answered. But thanks for your feedback anyway.